# When training a neural network on a windows machine, what can task manager tell me about how it's going?

Tags: pytorch

When I trained a simple convolutional network in pytorch, I could see in task manager that my cpu was hitting 100%, and I could see my ram spike up.

When running with CUDA, I could see my GPU, go from 0% to only 1-2% utilization.

I'm just curious about several things:

- I only ever see the Copy graph going up with the other 3 graphs (3D, video encode, video decode) doing nothing. Is that normal? I would've thought lots of matrix operations would make the 3D go up?
- I can easily max out CPU training, but I can never go above single digit % utilization for GPU training (and I don't even have a powerful GPU). I know it's because I probably have too simple a network, but besides increasing the batch size, are there ways to "take up slack"?